# Can I replace the reflection tool used by Linqpad?

Tags: reflection, linqpad

Linqpad uses Reflector to give its context help and Reflector is no longer free. How can I update Linqpad to use a different reflection tool like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/?dotnetblog) or anything else out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an OSS plugin that uses IlSpy called [LinqPadSpy](http://vincpa.github.io/linqpadspy/) which decompiles your code with ILSpy via the DumpDasm() extension method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the reflection tool at present. Let me know if there's a specific tool that you want - however bear in mind that it must allow an external program to navigate to a assembly, type and member.

Comment: I have no preference on a replacement. I was just put off a little that the free Reflector is not an option for me now. The integration is really nice and I would like to see that feature come back to those of us without the paid Reflector app.